# Hadoop data node shutting down with message 'libhadoop cannot be loaded'

Tags: hadoop, datanode

I'm trying to start datanode on new slaves in order to add them to a live hadoop cluster. But failing to start datanode with command **hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode**

I have created file **/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket** manually and also changed its permissions. I have also checked libraries which are all there.

Have checked other questions related to datanode shutting down but unable to solve issue. Also the error logs I'm getting is different as follows.

Any help is appreciated.

```
2018-11-22 13:31:03,485 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting DataNode with maxLockedMemory = 0
2018-11-22 13:31:03,512 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened streaming server at /0.0.0.0:50010
2018-11-22 13:31:03,515 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwidth is 10485760 bytes/s
2018-11-22 13:31:03,515 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Number threads for balancing is 50
2018-11-22 13:31:03,516 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.lang.RuntimeException: Although a UNIX domain socket path is configured as /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket, we cannot start a loca
lDataXceiverServer because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.getDomainPeerServer(DataNode.java:1166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initDataXceiver(DataNode.java:1137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:1369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:495)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2695)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2598)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2645)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2789)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2813)
2018-11-22 13:31:03,519 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.lang.RuntimeException: Although a UNIX domai
n socket path is configured as /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket, we cannot start a localDataXceiverServer because libhadoop cannot be lo
aded.
2018-11-22 13:31:03,521 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at HDP-slave-7/987.654.32.10
```

Comment: Got any solution??